# General formula for a series

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

I am trying to solve series of the form,

```
T(n) = T(n/4) + clog(n)
```

I am able to formulate a general formula for the T(n) term for the nth term. Its of the form

```
(2^k)T(n/2^2k) + k

k = 8clog(n/64) + 4clog(n/16) + 2clog(n/4) + clog(n)
```

but am having a hard time, summarizing the k terms together into a single formula. I have a basic idea of geometric and arithmatic progression, but cant figure this one out.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How $T(m)$ is defined when $m$ is not an integer?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio its basically calculating big-O for an algo. So its always positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining how you expanded your terms, did you mean the following recurrence?

$$T(n) = 2\:T\left( \frac{n}{4} \right) + c \log(n)$$

If so, solving it by rolling out the sequence and gleaning from the pattern is difficult. If you only want to know what $\Theta(T(n))$ is, then refer to the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) for solving recurrences of the form
$$T(n) = a\:T\left( \frac{n}{b} \right) + f(n)$$

For this particular example, the Master Theorem classifies that $T(n) \in \Theta\left( n^{\log_4(2)} \right) = \Theta\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$. But why?

Without using the Master Theorem, these recurrences can be solved using a (clever) inductive argument. To do so, first prove that there exist (not necessarily positive) constants $d$ and $e$ such that $T(n) \le d\sqrt{n} + e \log(n)$.

Likewise, you can use a symmetric induction argument for the lower bound.

As always, don't forget about the base case!

Comment: can we say that theta(n^1/2) is O(n^1/2)

Comment: @Scrooj Informally speaking, yes. Formally speaking, if $T(n) \in \theta\left(n^{1/2}\right)$, then $T(n) \in O\left(n^{1/2}\right)$ by definition of Big-Theta.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have a better understanding of the concept now. :)